# Binding Adapter pass array from XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have similer need, lets assume below example. I need to pass multiple fields to binding adapter.

```
@BindingAdapter("onClickListeners")
public static void setClicks(View view, View.OnClickListener[] onClickListeners)
```

So in XML, can I call it like this? -

```
onClickListeners="@{() -> handler.oneClicked(), () -> handler.secondClicked()}"
```

**Please note** -

1. The array should be dynamic for future use. So I can not take two params in Adapter.
2. I have multiple arrays fields so can not use `varargs`.

**Wanna see usecase -**

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"fullText", "highlightTexts", "highlightEnable", "onClickListeners"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setClickableHighLightedText(TextView tv, String fullText, String[] highlightTexts, boolean highlightEnable, View.OnClickListener[] onClickListeners) {
    tv.setText(fullText);
    if (highlightEnable) {
        for (int i = 0; i < highlightTexts.length; i++) {
            String highlightText = highlightTexts[i];
            Utilities.setClickableHighLightedText(tv, highlightText, onClickListeners.length > i ? onClickListeners[i] : null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try varargs instead of `[]`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi sir, nice to see you again. I am your big fan. Please see edit note.